# Randomly crashes in release configuration

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile, .net-native

While enabled **Optimize code** in project properties, application randomly crashes with exception

> Unhandled exception at 0x663B6243 (mrt100_app.dll) in 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x5502339B.

I think problem in `await
                 CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                     () => NavigateTo(pageType, extendedNavigationParameter));` and maybe here `if (Window.Current.Content is Frame)
                    {
                        var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                        frame.Navigate(pageType, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extendedNavigationParameter));
                    }`

Comment: on which platform do you get this crash? mobile or desktop?

Comment: on mobile platform

Comment: On your phone, go to Settings -> Update & Security -> For developers and set the value "Save this many crash dumps" to a vale > 0 (5 for example). After you get the app crash, connect the phone to your PC, navigate to \Documents\Debug directory and copy the dmp file to your PC.  Zip/Share the dmp, so that I can try to debug it.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? I have a similar problem with a code that was working before.

Comment: Yes, solved with "DoesNotOptimize=true" in *.rd file.
`<Assembly Name="MyAssembly" Serialize="Required All" Dynamic="Required All" DoNotOptimize="true"/>`

Comment: Thank you very much gruver. Setting this in Default.rd.xml works...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear answer for you but has the message says "Unhandled exception", you could try to locate the Exception by adding Try Catch blocks around both parts and log the exception.

Comment: I can't reproduce exception, it's random. While debug - one behavior, without debug - random crash.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the .NET Native Toolchain? 
Maybe your issue is caused by reflection in the json serialization. With the toolchain activated, reflection is not working anymore. Please read the following blog post for general information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600640(v=vs.110).aspx

And this link talks about serialization:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600638(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, i'm using .NET Native Toolchain. In Default.rd.xml have
    <Type Name="System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject" Dynamic="Required All" />
    <Type Name="MtsService.Common.ExtendedNavigationParameter"  Serialize="Required All"/>
    <Type Name="System.Object" Serialize="Required All"/>
    <Assembly Name="Model" Serialize="Required All"/>